# Symfony2 entity field type alternatives to "property" or "__toString()"?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Using Symfony2 [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) one should specify `property` option:

```
$builder->add('customers', 'entity', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'class'    => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Customer',
    'property' => 'first',
));
```

But sometimes this is not sufficient: think about two customers with the same name, so display the email (unique) would be mandatory.

Another possibility is to implement `__toString()` into the model:

```
class Customer
{
    public $first, $last, $email;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return sprintf('%s %s (%s)', $this->first, $this->last, $this->email);
    }
}
```

The disadvances of the latter is that you are **forced to display the entity the same way** in all your forms.

***Is there any other way to make this more flexible?*** I mean something like a callback function:

```
$builder->add('customers', 'entity', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'class'    => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Customer',
    'property' => function($data) {
         return sprintf('%s %s (%s)', $data->first, $data->last, $data->email);
     },
));
```

Comment: I have this exact same situation and was planning to post a question on SO soon... I'm looking forward to the answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found this really helpful, and I wound a really easy way to do this with your code so here is the solution

```
$builder->add('customers', 'entity', array(
'multiple' => true,
'class'    => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Customer',
'property' => 'label',
));
```

And in the class Customer (the Entity)

```
public function getLabel()
{
    return $this->lastname .', '. $this->firstname .' ('. $this->email .')';
}
```

eh voila :D the property get its String from the Entity not the Database.

Comment: You should probably use the getters and not access the values directly. `return $this->getLastname() .', '. $this->getFirstname() .' ('. $this->getEmail() .')';`

Comment: This is great, except if you need to generate a thumbnail or something that you can't do from the model...

Answer (score 2):

Passing a closure does not work yet, but will be added to Symfony soon: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4067

Comment: hm... but there is nothing said about closures for the entity form type.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this can be achievable by adding following block after `elseif ($this->labelPath)` block in [ObjectChoiceList.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ObjectChoiceList.php#L198).

```
elseif (is_callable($this->labelPath)) {
  $labels[$i] = call_user_func($this->labelPath, $choice);
}
```

Haven't tried it though :).

Comment: That does look like it would work, but require hacking Symfony. I would prefer to avoid that if possible. Surely there is a "correct" way to do this. It seems to me like a fairly substantial issue.

Comment: Well it is the only way AFIK. To make it to Symfony2 core a PR needs to be send to github. I may submit a PR with proper unit test if I get free time. If any one submit a PR that is also good.

Comment: @m2mdas Let us know if you do submit a PR. I'm not hurting for this functionality right now but I will be at some point and may do it myself if someone else hasn't taken care of this by then.