# Option groups in symfony2 entity form type

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

Is there any way an entity field can be shown grouped in option groups in symfony2 (v.2.1), for example I have something like this in my form class:

```
$builder->add('account',
                    'entity',
                    array(
                        'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Account',
                        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repo){
                            return $repo->findAllAccounts();
                        },
                        'required'  => true,
                        'empty_value' => 'Choose_an_account',
                    );
```

But (of course) they are displayed as the repository class reads it from the db and I would like to display them grouped in the combobox. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10403249/115193) mentions that featured added to the 2.2 release out of the box, but what options do we 2.1 users have?

The Grouping would be based on a field called `Type`, lets say I have a getter for that called `getType()` in my Account entity that returns a string.

Thanks.

Comment: Grouped by means of what criterion? E.g. by category so then you wanna display the category and the list of items from that category?

Comment: Is [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244376/select-with-optgroup-in-symfony-2-0) helpful? If yes, you can construct the array of choices at runtime by doing a query to your entity repository.

Comment: Any news? Did your problem can be resolved by the <optgroup> tag? In this case I have the answer... Otherwise, please add a textual example of the desired output!

Comment: Thank you, I think It can be constructed at runtime since no functionality of that kind is built in the version of the framework I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a similar thing when handling with categories.

First, when you build the form, pass the list of choices as a result from a function `getAccountList()` as follows:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder        
            ->add('account', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Account',
                'choices' => $this->getAccountList(),
                'required'  => true,
                'empty_value' => 'Choose_an_account',
            ));
}
```

The function should do something like follows (the content depend on the way you structure your result).

```
private function getAccountList(){
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('MyBundle\Entity\Account');

    $list = array();

    //Now you have to construct the <optgroup> labels. Suppose to have 3 groups
    $list['group1'] = array();
    $list['group2'] = array();
    $list['group3'] = array(); 

    $accountsFrom1 = $repo->findFromGroup('group1'); // retrieve your accounts in group1.
    foreach($accountsFrom1 as $account){
        $list[$name][$account->getName()] = $account;
    }
    //....etc

    return $list;
}
```

Of course, you can do it more dynamics! Mine is just a brief example!

You also have to pass the `EntityManager` to your custom form class. So, define the constructor:

```
class MyAccountType extends AbstractType {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em){
        $this->em = $em; 
    }    
}
```

And pass the `EntityManager` when you initiate the `MyAccountType` object.