# How to display db result array in Twig using Angular.js in Symfony 2.3?

Tags: angularjs, symfony-2.3

I am trying to include angular.js in my project which is created using Symfony 2.3.
I converted the result array to json using json_encode function in controller

```
function displayAction(){
    $user=  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DemoBundle:Users');
    $result = $user->findAll();
    $res= json_encode($result);
    $res->header->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $this->render('DemoBundle:Demo:demoView.html.twig',array('results'=>$res));
}
```

to initialise it in ng-init,

```
<div ng-init= "result= {{results}}"></div>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="res in result">
      <td>[[res.id]]</td>
      <td>[[res.username]]</td>
      <td>[[res.password]]</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

but it gives me an empty array of json.

Comment: If you are using angular the binding expression is `{{}}` not `[[]]`

Comment: i knew this, but twig also use {{}} to display values , so i changed angular braces {{}} to [[]] using this code.                        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
            });

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has no sense return a json to process it in the Twig template. Maybe you need to  ask for the json resource on angularjs controller (with $http or via $resource) and get the data from the model (no ng-init).

If you still want to do it, maybe you get some help from here: [Decoding JSON in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig)