# How to access array variable from a twig file

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a controller which returns all menus. From twig file, i use to access controller to get all menus.

I could just see all my menus in my twig file.

Code:

Twig File :

```
{% set menulist%}{%render url('get_all_menus')%}{% endset %}
```

I use for loop to print my menu name. Like

```
{% for menu in menulist %}

    {{menu.MenuName}}

{%endfor%}
```

But I don't get any values from the above for loop. When I use dump(menu-list) I get result as

```
[{"FunctionName":"Home","ModuleName":null,"SubModuleName":null,"PageURL":"home_page","AccessLevel":"2"}]
```

Which is a JSON data that I return from my controller. How can i get the values from my for loop? Am i making any mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are rendering another controller? It performs second request to application. Create custom twig function to return menu elements -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html 
That will be faster and JSON problem should disappear. Or if you don't want to create twig function - render partial menu twig file in controller action with name 'get_all_menus'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store menu result in one variable like below :

And used [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function for convert your json data into array than you can get your menu data through loop.

```
$menuJsonData = '[{"FunctionName":"Home","ModuleName":null,"SubModuleName":null,"PageURL":"home_page","AccessLevel":"2"}]';

$menuData = json_decode($test);

foreach($menuData as $menu){
    echo $menu->FunctionName;
}
```

Comment: I can do this in my controller, but i would like to do this in twig file. Is this possible in twig file???

Comment: @user2743855 please check this link for decode json data in twig file : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig