# how to decode json with twig?

Tags: php, json, twig, decode

I'm creating a website where users can uploads some images, URL images are saved into json and inserted into database so when I select all of the rows in the table it gives me something this.

```
{
"sroxrafm72pgipmpa4nz":
 "http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dok4nvr2e\/image\/upload\/v1444610510\/sroxrafm72pgipmpa4nz.jpg"
},
{
"egrrhg4umqgyjoltxrky":
"http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dok4nvr2e\/image\/upload\/v1444610511\/egrrhg4umqgyjoltxrky.jpg"
},
{
"rfurg40o5af2h6s55thb":
"http:\/\/res.cloudinary.com\/dok4nvr2e\/image\/upload\/v1444610511\/rfurg40o5af2h6s55thb.jpg"
}
```

I need to decode it with twig to get the url of each id to display the images, but I just can't figure out to do this. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You should probably decode it before passing it to twig, or you could use JavaScript and do it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a clone of: [Decoding JSON in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig)

What might be easier is to base64 encode the images and store the string inside of the database. I use the following:

In HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
function getImageBase64($image_path) {
    $image = imagecreatefromfile($image_path);
    ob_start();
    imagepng($image);
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $image_string = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($contents);
    imagedestroy($image);

    return $image_string;
}

if (getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) !== false) {
    $image = getImageBase64($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

    //Add to database...
}
```