# Twig loop through JSON

Tags: php, json, loops, twig

```
Array
(
    [page_title] => Slovak RS
    [page_footer] => © Copyright 2017
    [is_published] => published
    [menu] => {
    "id":"1",
    "name": "main_menu",
    "items": [
        "pos1": [
        "display_name" : "Informácie",
        "path"         : "informacie"
    ],
        "pos2": [
        "display_name" : "Videá",
        "path"         : "video"
    ],
        "pos4": [
        "display_name" : "Recepty",
        "path"         : "recepty"
    ],
        "pos5": [
        "display_name" : "Galéria",
        "path"         : "galeria"
    ],
        "pos6": [
        "display_name" : "Osobnosti",
        "path"         : "osobnosti"
    ],
    ],
    "updated_at": "2020"
 }
)
```

This is data I'm getting into twig template file. I want to have menu in single db table stored as json. I can show items like `{{ menu }}, {{ page_title }}`, but have hard times looping through that json part

This is what i tried

```
 {% for item in menu %}
    {{ item.id }}
    {{ item['id'] }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for key,value in menu %}
    Key : {{ key }}
    Value : {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
```

I'm using twig 2.x and I'm newbie

Comment: is not possible decode in the twig template, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504988/2270041) solutions if is good for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) the JSON first, before you're passing it to twig. With that, you have an array or object, that you can loop through.

```
$objJson = json_decode($yourDBArray['menu']);
$arrJson = json_decode($yourDBArray['menu'],true);
```

In the code you've provided, the JSON is a `string` and not an `array` nor an `object`.