# how to convert string which looks like array to array using twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I have a string ["a", "b", "c"] which looks like an array. How would I covert it into an array using twig. I am looking for an equivalent of JSON.parse(string) in this case.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post some example code so we can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding JSON in Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig)