# Accessing a decoded json string value in twig

Tags: json, symfony

I am working on a Symfony project and need to loop through data to populate saved fields in a form (specifically the number of bed types in a property). I save the data in the database table as a json string, as follows:

```
{"2":"5","3":"0","4":"0","5":"0","6":"0","7":"0"}
```

This JSON follows the structure `"BEDID": NUMBER OF BEDS`. I implemented the solution regarding decoding json in twig as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504988/5194337 but I am having trouble actually being able to access each specific value in the decoded json. I use this in the twig template to decode the json (based on the fact my data is stored in a variable called `specifics` and `website.id` references one of multiple websites owned by the user:

```
{% set beds = specifics[website.id].0.standardBedTypes|json_decode  %}
```

So, once I do this, I try and access the value of each number of beds as follows:

```
{{ beds[standard_bed.id] }}
```

`standard_bed` being the value in the for loop. But, when I load the page I get the following error:

> Impossible to access a key "2" on an object of class "stdClass" that
>   does not implement ArrayAccess interface.

I guess this means that the decoded value of the json is technically not an array, but I cannot think of any other method of referencing each value, so help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Please add some code... It's hard to follow what is what, even more so to create a local test for your description. That said, is it really a good idea to decode the string in the template? Why not have the model class do it? This way you don't repeat the same code in multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/json_encode.html), you can pass it as an option. See the options [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php).

You want to pass `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY`

> Decodes JSON objects as PHP array.

So basically you want to do:

```
{% set beds = specifics[website.id].0.standardBedTypes|json_decode(constant('JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY'))  %}
```

If you want to access to objects properties, you can do it using the [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function.

Comment: The attribute function is what I needed here - was able to access each value using `attribute(beds, standard_bed.id)`