# Why isn't there a native json_decode in Twig?

Tags: twig, twig-filter

I know [how to set up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504988/3321344) a `json_decode` function in twig.. but why is there no native support for decoding in twig? I can easily call `json_encode` without setting up a Twig Filter, but that is not the case for `json_decode`.

It seems logical to have it has a native function. Am I missing the rational behind not having it? Maybe it's computationally expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode` makes sense, `json_decode` however does not really.

It adds a non trivial dependency towards the fact that the data passed is JSON.

Filters are here to **transform** data not **crafting** data. Computations (that are not transformations) should be made ahead of time.

One could also argue that `json_encode` should be done ahead of time but considering how frequent it is to return/send JSON it seems fair enough to do it in the template.

PS :
This seems to be a primarily opinion based question (unless there is an official answer to it).

Comment: That makes sense. I was curious if there was official documentation about it, or some computer science theory behind it. Thanks!