# Twig - Set twig variables from manifest.json

Tags: json, symfony, twig, templating, craftcms

I'm trying to implement a Webpack environment on my Craft 3 projects. In order to dynamically call my hashed resources I'm outputting the in a `manifest.json` file and importing it into my template.

**manifest.json**

```
{"app":["js/app3bfb132e4187389fccd4.js","css/app53079ca4a05210b4af0c.css"],"vendor":"js/vendor49171fe3f01c19da9296.js"}
```

**index.twig**

```
{% set manifest %}
    {% include './manifest.json' %}
{% endset %}
```

The output of that variable is a string. Is there anyway to encode it so that the variables are accessible/printable using only Twig? (Using `{{ manifest.app }}` for example)

Comment: you will need to `json_decode` the string

Comment: There is no native `json_decode` in Twig  :(

Comment: Add it with a `filter/function`? See [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/extending-twig.html)

Comment: If you want to use the manifest to look up the 'real' filenames, the Symfony/asset component is designed to do that. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html#json-file-manifest

Answer (score 2):

You have to decode the JSON first. I would suggest one of the two approaches:

- Create custom `manifest` function for Twig which will return decoded manifest object
- or create `json_decode` filter for Twig, decode included json content and use it

**manifest function**

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

class ManifestExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $manifestFile;

    public function __construct($manifestFile)
    {
        $this->manifestFile = $manifestFile;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('manifest', array($this, 'manifest')),
        );
    }

    public function manifest()
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($this->manifestFile);

        return json_decode($content);
    }
}
```

You can register it as a service in `services.yml` providing path to the manifest.json file.

```
App\Twig\ManifestExtension:
    class: 'App\Twig\ManifestExtension'
    arguments: ['%kernel.project_dir%/../public/manifest.json']
    tags: [twig.extension]
```

Usage:

```
{% set manifest = manifest() %}
```

**json_decode filter**

It's already been covered here:

[Decoding JSON in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig)

Usage:

```
{% set manifest %}
    {% include './manifest.json' %}
{% endset %}

{% set manifest = manifest | json_decode %}
```