# Display json data with Symfony 4 Form component

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

I've been trying to display form with data json. I can't understand what I need to do that form have several input fields with TextType? One value json in one input field.

I know how view json array in twig without component form but I want view json with `Symfony 4` component form.

**This is json array**

```
[{"name":"PHP","image":"php.png"},{"name":"java","image":"java.png"},{"name":"postgresql","image":"postgresql.png"},{"name":"JS","image":"js.png"}]
```

This is my code:

**Class ProjectsController**

```
class ProjectsController extends BaseAdminController {

  public function createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view)
  {
    $formBuilder = parent::createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view);

    $formBuilder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('technology', ProjectTechnologyType::class)
        ->add('type', ProjectType::class)
        ->add('url');

    return $formBuilder;
  }
}
```

**Class ProjectTechnologyType**

```
class ProjectTechnologyType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
        ->add('image', ProjectJsonType::class);

    $builder->get('image')
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($technologyAsArray) {
                return json_encode($technologyAsArray);
            },
            function ($technologyAsJson) {
                return json_decode($technologyAsJson);
            }
        ));
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => ProjectTechnology::class
    ));
  }
}
```

**Class ProjectJsonType**

```
class ProjectJsonType extends AbstractType{

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults([]);
  }

  public function getParent()
  {
    return CollectionType::class;
  }
}
```

**Twig**

```
{% block main %}
{% block entity_form %}
    {{ form_row(form.title) }}
    {{ form_row(form.description) }}
    {{ form_row(form.type) }}
    {{ form_row(form.technology) }}
    {{ form_row(form.url) }}
{% endblock entity_form %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your post is probably duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig

Comment: @thafirstone I don't think so. This has nothing to do with Twig, but with Form Transformers.