# How to Decode JSON in Twig Symfony 4.3

Tags: json, symfony-4.3

How to decode a JSON data in Twig this is my code in my controller

```
public function testoutput($id) {
$form = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository(ApplicationForm::class)
->findAll();

return $this->render('testoutput.html.twig', array('form' => $form));}
```

My database looks like this.

```
id |             jsonData             | dateSigned
===|================================= |============
1  | {"fname":"Jan", "lname": "Jake"} | 10-09-2019 
===|==================================|===========
2  | {"fname":"Mike", "lname": "Ham"} | 10-10-2019 
===|==================================|===========
```

I want to display this data on my Twig View but I am getting this error

> Unknown "json_decode" filter. Did you mean "json_encode"?

I research about this error but it seems the results and codes are already outdated still using Symfony 2 about 6 years ago. The folders and structures are already new in Symfony 4.3. Is there any new way to solve.

```
{% for data in form %}
{% set a = data.data_json | json_decode() %}

{% for json is a %}
    {{ json['fname'] }}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting...

Comment: Unknown "json_decode" filter. Did you mean "json_encode"?

Comment: Possible duplicate please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig/14504988

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding JSON in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig)

Comment: doesn't work anymore

Comment: i dont know how to setup this in my services.yaml file it prompts up an error.<service id="some_id" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\VarsExtension">
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
</service>