# Add json from static json file to index.twig with twig include

Tags: json, twig

I'm struggling with json in twig. I want to include a static json file to my twig file and pass it to a twig include inside that.

I have my index twig file where I have my STATIC json file include and twig include:

```
{% set json %}
    {% include "content.json" %}
{% endset %}

{% include '@partials/blocks/site-header.twig' with {json:json} %}
```

In My siteheader.twig I would like to render my navigation something like:

```
{% for headerNav in json %}

<a class="button button--nav" href="#">
{{headerNav.text}}
</a>

{% endfor %}
```

My content.json looks like this:

```
{
    "headerNav":[
        {
            "text": "Link 1"
        },
        {
            "text": "Link 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The whole point is that the siteheader should be able to render different links dependant on which   json file i pass into it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding JSON in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500698/decoding-json-in-twig)

Comment: Anyone? Every kind of answer about static json and twig would help :-)

Comment: .. Did you read the question/answers in the link I've added?

Comment: Yes I did.
It seems it is more targeted dynamic json created on the server by php or .net 
What I am looking for is how to pass json into a twig include and the json is a flat .json file in the file system. Did i miss something in the post you are reffering to?

Comment: Twig is not able to work `JSON` directly, therefor you need to decode it first. Then you can loop it.