# Show 2 names in an entity choice inside FormType symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have this code inside my `ClutchType`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $currentUser = $this->currentUser;
    $builder
        ->add('breedingPair')
        ->add('breedingPair', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs',
            'property' => 'id',
            'property' => 'breeding_pair_male',
            'placeholder' => 'Choose a breeding pair',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('br')
                    ->where('br.user = :currentUser')
                    ->orderBy('br.breedingPairDate')
                    ->setParameter('currentUser', $currentUser);
            }
        ))
        ->add('laidDate')
        ->add('estimatedHatchStart')
        ->add('estimatedHatchEnd')
        ->add('hatchDate')
        ->add('eggAmount')
        ->add('breedingSeason')
    ;
}
```

Which works fine and brings out the male inside a breeding pair. How can i make it so it shows both the male and the females name in the drop down? I've tried:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $currentUser = $this->currentUser;
    $builder
        ->add('breedingPair')
        ->add('breedingPair', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs',
            'property' => 'id',
            'property' => 'breeding_pair_male',
            'property' => 'breeding_pair_female',
            'placeholder' => 'Choose a breeding pair',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('br')
                    ->where('br.user = :currentUser')
                    ->orderBy('br.breedingPairDate')
                    ->setParameter('currentUser', $currentUser);
            }
        ))
        ->add('laidDate')
        ->add('estimatedHatchStart')
        ->add('estimatedHatchEnd')
        ->add('hatchDate')
        ->add('eggAmount')
        ->add('breedingSeason')
    ;
}
```

But obviously you can't show more than one value in the property.

So what i have at the moment looks like this:

[image: Dropdown]

But i would like it to show both the male and female names next to each other. Currently it is only pulling the male's name.

Here is my SQL table that shows there is an ID for a male and a female

[image]

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10218529/3675759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `property` option in your `->add('breedingPair', 'entity'` call can be set to any user-defined method you like, so within your `Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs` entity you could define a method that returns the string you want, e.g.

```
public function getPairAsString()
{
    return sprintf(
        '%s & %s', 
        $this->breedingPairMale->getName(), 
        $this->breedingPairFemale->getName()
    );
}
```

and then in your `ClutchType` you would add the field as follows:

```
$builder->add('breedingPair', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs',
    'property' => 'pairAsString',
    'placeholder' => 'Choose a breeding pair',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser)         {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('br')
            ->where('br.user = :currentUser')
            ->orderBy('br.breedingPairDate')
            ->setParameter('currentUser', $currentUser);
    }
))
```

Comment: I shall give this a go when i'm home from work. Thank you for the information :)

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware you could do this, thank you